# ansible : is there a method to avoid skipped messages from specific roles

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

*I m not looking for ansible.cfg skippy variable method* but for a method I can use in **specific roles only** to avoid skipped messages on stout while running my playbooks.

(*cannot use solutions based on grep rejections cause my ansible commands are not launched from a shell or similar but some applications*) I can  only work on yml files.

How to do that ?

test file

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    mypath: /tmp/file
  tasks:
    - stat: path={{mypath}}
      register: foo

    - debug: var=foo

    - name: do something with file if exists
      command: cat {{ mypath }}
      when: foo.stat.exists
```

here it fails to avoid the skip message application runs only "ansible-playbook filename" & cannot be modified to include any pipes contrary of  the example below  :

```
-bash-4.4$ ansible-playbook filetest.yml  | grep -i skip
skipping: [localhost]
```

If its not possible is it possible on specific playbook at last ?

I repeat I cannot use cfg file solutions at all  only environnement variables or an "inside yml" syntax

Thanks.

Comment: You can do whatever you like with custom callbacks.

Comment: I can only modify yaml's I cannot use any plugins callback inside the ansible.cfg.  I will try to use system variable `export ANSIBLE_LOAD_CALLBACK_PLUGINS=1` I hope it can work.  ... think it cannot work cause it needs to install plugins for general environnement et not for specific

Comment: tried on my laptop this fails   I see the skipped messages

Comment: So it is not a solution . I confirm  using it as an environment variable doesn't work. Or Need more modifications to call it from files but then how ? is there an example (not found on ansible official site)

Comment: You need `ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK` setting

Comment: I can't use it I can't modify the ansible commands as already said higher :)  so I won't be able to use the `ansible-playbook -v ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK .......etc....`  I think I will need to ask application rewriting  & loose many weeks....  then...

Comment: Did you find a way? I also have this requirement.

Comment: not something really satisfying .. a little rewrite of the application & some output filtering from scripts that launches the playbook

Answer (score -5):

in the ansible.cfg put
stdout_callback = skippy